# WinCE batch format SD Card?

Tags: windows-ce, sd-card, exfat

I need to format many SD cards in WinCE. I am not familiar with CE, currently I'm using the CE storage manager to format them but it takes a long time and doing something many times leads to mistakes.

Is there any way to format a SD card via batch file? And what are the options? I need Part00 -> ExFAT & Part01  -> ExFAT with TFAT

Thanks in advance.

Basti

Comment: Did you find any workaround for your problem?

Comment: Hi, Khaled... No unfortunately not. Windows CE seems to be something mysterical and secret. The problem beeing, that many of the makers can trim the CE down to whatever they want and many times some libraries are missing... So you cannot give an 'will always work' answer